# Prime gaps of the form 2+6n are equally as numerous as those of the form 4+6n, and exactly half as numerous as those of the form 2+4n

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Has this conjecture been proved?

Taking, for example all the prime numbers from 3 to 100,000,000

The total number of all the gaps equal to either 2 or 8 or 14 or 20...etc is 1,616,471
The total number  of all the gaps equal to either 4 or 10 or 16 or 22..etc is 1,616,470
and the total number of all the gaps equal to either 2 or 6 or 10 or 14....etc equals 3,206,361

as a corollary prime gaps of the form 6, 12, 18,....etc are just as numerous as those taking the form
4, 8, 12, 16 etc

Answer (score 1):

Conjectures of this type, which are equivalent to looking at the distribution of congruences classes of pairs of consecutive primes, are almost certainly true but beyond our ability to prove at the moment. For a good summary of the state of the art, see [this paper by Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan](https://www.pnas.org/content/113/31/E4446).